# A process now in progress, with no agent

Tags: middle-voice, aspect

Suppose I want to say:

> Maybe your appetite is a sign of returning health.

One possibility:

> Fortasse orexis tua sānitātem portendit revertentem.

I'm not sure that *revertor* carries this metaphor as easily in Latin as "return" can in English. I think *restituere* would be a stronger, clearer verb, so let's try that—and this will explain my question, which is more general than just how to word one sentence:

> Fortasse orexis tua sānitātem **restituere** portendit.
>
> Fortasse orexis tua sānitātem portendit **restituentem**.

These both sound wrong to my semi-educated ear. Doesn't **restituō** mean that its object is being restored, not its subject? I've come across suggestions that Latin allows a "middle voice" with almost as much flexibility as in English—but even in English, "Your health is restoring" sounds a little odd. A typical usage might be *rēgem restituere*: to restore the king to his throne; *rex restituit* would require an object: what the king is reinstating.

The infinitive also sounds wrong to me. The idea to be communicated in the sentence is that restoration of health might be *in process* right now, with no suggestion of completion. I understand the present tense to express that; the infinitive seems less clear. Maybe I'm being led too much by my native English, but a present participle seems ideal here—but present participles can only be active.

How does Latin express this notion of the action of a verb being now in progress, incomplete, without bringing in a separate agent?

Passive voice? But doesn't this suggest that some unnamed external agent is doing the restoration or healing?

> Fortasse orexis tua sānitātem **restituī** portendit.
> Fortasse orexis tua **tē sānārī** portendit.
> Fortasse orexis tua portendit ut **sānēris**.

This seems clumsy:

> Fortasse orexis tua sānitātis **restitūtiōnem** portendit.

Must we choose an intransitive verb? Put in a reflexive agent by analogy with *sē movēre*? Something completely different?

> Fortasse orexis tua sānitātem portendit **recrēscēns**.
> Fortasse orexis tua **tē tē sānāre** portendit. (??)
> Fortasse orexis tua portendit ut **tē sānēs**?
> Fortasse orexis tua significat ut **validus fīās dē novō**.
> Fortasse orexe tuā **valēscere** sē monstrat.
> Fortasse orexe tuā vidēmus **tē valēscere**.
> **Quia valēscās** famēs augēscit.

---

By the way, I haven't encountered **orexis** in any reading; I looked it up after rejecting *appetitiō* and *appetītus* as ambiguous without context. Finding a word in a dictionary is often a poor guide to using it properly, so please correct me in the comments if I've got that or anything else wrong, and I'll update the question. I don't want to distract from the main question about verbs.

Answer (score 6):

I'd suggest four approaches:

1. A good way to convey a middle-voiced meaning is Latin is to use a reflexive pronoun.

   > *Fortasse orexis tua sānitātem portendit **sē** restituentem.*
   > = Maybe your appetite is a sign of your health restoring itself.
   > ≈ Maybe your appetite is a sign of returning health.
2. You can also use *reverti*.
   Check out part II.A [in the L&S entry for *revertere/reverti*](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=reverto&fromdoc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059) for an example of *ad sanitatem reverti* in Caesar.
   Granted, the examples suggest that the person should return to health rather than health returning to the person.
   But you can do just that:

   > *Fortasse orexis tua **tē ad** sānitātem portendit revertentem.*
3. Look for different verbs for improvement and consider using particles or adverbs.
   Different languages have different selections.
   One option in Latin is *meliorescere*.
   The prefix *re-* is quite productive, so I would not be opposed to taking the liberty to derive.
   But you can also check verbs starting with this prefix to see what is certainly within good *Latinitas*.
   Or replace *re-* with *iterum*, *rursum*, *retro*, or some such word.
   So perhaps:

   > *Sanitas tua orexis tuae causa redire videtur.*
4. Find just the right word.
   Latin has the verb *resanescere*, "to become healthy again".
   There is also *resanare*.

   > *Orexis te resanescere monstrat.*

   This is an appealing wording: it seems to deliver the original message clearly but briefly.
   This therefore (and otherwise) strikes me as idiomatic.

A key question is:
How faithful do you want to be to the original English structure?
If not very, there are a number of different angles of approach to play with.

Comment: Preserving English structure is of no interest. I'd like to know how one conceives of and expresses this in the Latin way of thinking and speaking: _quomodo haec idea Latine formatur._

Comment: @BenKovitz Then you might be interested in the fourth option I added. The others seem pretty verbose in comparison. I'm not going to discuss *orexis* as a word here (it deserves a separate question), but otherwise I am happy with the simplicity of the fourth solution.